# Is there any hospitality network for vegans?

Tags: veganism, traveling, resources

Hospitality networks (such as [SERVAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servas_International), [Hospitality club](http://www.hospitalityclub.org/), [Couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.com/) and [BeWelcome](https://www.bewelcome.org/)) are networks of travelers and people who host them. Recently "specialized" websites, like [TrustRoots](https://www.trustroots.org/) that is for hitchhikers have begin to appear.

Is there any hospitality network for vegans?

Comment: I don't know and I'd like to know. You can search for vegan hosts on Couchsurfing quite well, though.

Comment: @Turion this could be part of the answer! (also with instructions of how to do it)

Comment: What a wonderful question! The checklist for a vegan hospice of any kind would be extensive... that doesn't mean it's not something we want. Meanwhile, I presume you know the app HappyCow - for vegan restaurants, cafes, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I learned about [Veg Visits](https://www.vegvisits.com/) on my most recent travels, a home sharing platform similar to airbnb, that allows you to stay at houses with vegan / vegetarian kitchens.

I did not use it however, so  I can't speak much to its ease of use or successfulness.